# How can I add a Haskell package from GitHub to my shell.nix file?

Tags: haskell, nix

So I have a Haskell project that has a shell.nix that looks like this:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  ghc = pkgs.haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
    regex-compat lucid replace-attoparsec hspec cabal-install text-regex-replace optparse-generic lens-regex-pcre clay bytestring charsetdetect AhoCorasick
  ]);
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "my-haskell-env";
  buildInputs = [ ghc ];
  shellHook = "eval $(egrep ^export ${ghc}/bin/ghc)";
}
```

But AhoCorasick is broken, and I need to install a custom version of it, from here:

https://github.com/stackbuilders/AhoCorasick

How do I do that? I imagine it's something using `pkgs.fetchFromGitHub`, but I can't even seem to find documentation for this in the Nix manuals.

Edit: here's what I'm trying so far:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  myAhoCorasickSrc = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "stackbuilders";
    repo  = "AhoCorasick";
    rev = "cbf76b78612c66e51eb02f24162ace49325c5d61";
    sha256 = "0ci5rywh042yi4ild3i7kx09rmj5v5iswzsah47f8axj1kq5vlci";
  };
  myAhoCorasick = pkgs.haskellPackages.callCabal2nix myAhoCorasickSrc {};
  ghc = pkgs.haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
    regex-compat
    lucid
    replace-attoparsec
    hspec
    cabal-install
    text-regex-replace
    optparse-generic
    lens-regex-pcre
    clay
    bytestring
    charsetdetect
    myAhoCorasick
  ]);
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "my-haskell-env";
  buildInputs = [ ghc ];
  shellHook = "eval $(egrep ^export ${ghc}/bin/ghc)";
}
```

What's strange is that it just seems to return a shell, but the package is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override a Haskell package with a git / local package with Nix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414329/how-do-i-override-a-haskell-package-with-a-git-local-package-with-nix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to weave your package into the `haskellPackages` set:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  myAhoCorasickSrc = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "stackbuilders";
    repo  = "AhoCorasick";
    rev = "cbf76b78612c66e51eb02f24162ace49325c5d61";
    sha256 = "0ci5rywh042yi4ild3i7kx09rmj5v5iswzsah47f8axj1kq5vlci";
  };

  myHaskellPackages = pkgs.haskellPackages.override {
    overrides = self: super: with pkgs.haskell.lib; {
      AhoCorasick = super.callCabal2nix "AhoCorasick" myAhoCorasickSrc {};

      clay = doJailbreak (unmarkBroken super.clay);

      replace-attoparsec = super.callHackageDirect {
        pkg = "replace-attoparsec";
        ver = "1.2.0.0";
        sha256 = "0vgvrcv1inf90s620f48ixikpb9rfffq0mc1fxg7ffi8c0sijc2n";
      } {};
    };
  };

  ghc = myHaskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
    regex-compat
    lucid
    replace-attoparsec
    hspec
    cabal-install
    text-regex-replace
    optparse-generic
    lens-regex-pcre
    clay
    bytestring
    charsetdetect
    AhoCorasick
  ]);
in
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "my-haskell-env";
  buildInputs = [ ghc ];
}
```

(Also, `replace-attoparsec` was not present in my nixpkgs, so I had to add that, and `clay` was marked broken because its bounds were too narrow for the `hspec`/`hspec-discover` in my nixpkgs.)

Comment: Also, that particular github revision does not seem to compile, but I don't think that's Nix's fault.