# Building a Haskell nix expression from GitHub fails when passing optional build argument

Tags: haskell, github, nix

**Problem.** I am building a nix expression `godot-haskell` from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/SimulaVR/godot-haskell/blob/simula/default.nix) which

- Has/requires git submodules to compile properly
- Takes an optional build argument `godot-api` that I'd like to use

If I manually clone this repo (recursively via `git clone --recursive`), and then

```
let 
  # ...
  godot-haskell = haskellPackages.callPackage /local/path/to/default.nix { api-json = godot-api; };
  # ...
in 
  # ...
```

then everything works fine! But if instead I try to do this non-locally:

```
godot-haskell-nix = "${fetchFromGitHub {
  fetchSubmodules = true;
  owner = "SimulaVR";
  repo = "godot-haskell";
  rev =  "df592f8e12647ed58d7ba6da4cf40a382d83725e";
  sha256 = "05wp8lzj2xqwkif8hw9l4byw0dfm3y3jaccsvjif4izfwycj91r8";
  }}/default.nix";

godot-haskell = haskellPackages.callPackage godot-haskell-nix { api-json = godot-api; };  # <- With the `api-json` build argument
```

then I get

```
error: anonymous function at /nix/store/xnf67r119iazf828ixny8wjyzl01hwsg-source/default.nix:1:1 called with unexpected argument 'api-json', at /nix/store/7knlwgidnagqrckm5h051i4rxjf3l68z-nixpkgs-20.03pre211220.1144ee55385/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:87:27
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

**Question:** Why does this work fine when done locally, but suddenly fail when using `fetchFromGitHub`? How to get around this error?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414329/how-do-i-override-a-haskell-package-with-a-git-local-package-with-nix-when-usi/56416694

Answer (score 1):

`cat /nix/store/xnf67r119iazf828ixny8wjyzl01hwsg-source/default.nix` shows:

```
{ mkDerivation, aeson, ansi-wl-pprint, base, bytestring, c2hs
, casing, colour, containers, hpack, lens, linear, mtl, parsec
, parsers, stdenv, stm, template-haskell, text
, unordered-containers, vector
}:

mkDerivation {
  pname = "godot-haskell";
  version = "3.1.0.0";
  src = ./.;
  libraryHaskellDepends = [
    aeson ansi-wl-pprint base bytestring casing colour containers lens
    linear mtl parsec parsers stm template-haskell text
    unordered-containers vector
  ];
  libraryToolDepends = [ c2hs hpack ];
  doHaddock = false;
  preConfigure = "hpack";
  homepage = "https://github.com/KaneTW/godot-haskell#readme";
  description = "Haskell bindings for the Godot game engine API";
  license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
}
```

No `api-json` argument! So the difference isn't in how nix is evaluating the local files vs the `fetchFromGitHub` ones, the difference is that they're not the same content!

Sure enough, I had a look at revision `df592f8e12647ed58d7ba6da4cf40a382d83725e` of that repo. It's the latest commmit on the `master` branch. However the link you included in your question goes to the `simula` branch, which includes commits that haven't made it to `master` yet.

Try using `rev = "45f15cf95e5a7228bed0739e020d4c404c3af49e";` (you'll have to update the nix hash as well, of course).